# How to Pass Parameter to funcCall in Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have to pass an extra parameter to funcCall method. How to do that? And What is the use of i in the parameter? I hav to add another parameter probably like this.

```
<input type="text" id="phone" class="validate[funcCall[checkPhoneNumber["phone"]]]"/><input type="text" id="mobile" class="validate[funcCall[checkPhoneNumber["mobile"]]]"/>
```

I hav to add switch case inside the following method for phone and mobile which will hav the different regex.

```
function checkPhoneNumber(field, rules, i, options){    
    alert(i);
    if (!field.val().match(/^[0-9]{8,15}$/))        
        return options.allrules.phone.alertText;  
    else if (!field.val().match(/([^((\+)*(0*))])/))         
        return options.allrules.phone.alertText;  
    }
```

Comment: its very hard to guess without seeing the relevant code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using attribute for each input tag and I'm getting the value of that attribute and based on that I'm using my functionality. For example:

```
var data =  field.attr("validationfor"));
if(data=="PhoneNumber"){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap the function call in an anonymous function

$("").click(function( **HERE you add any arguments that jquery sends 1** ) { **YourFunction**( **HERE you add all arguments for your function and can include the arguments from 1** ); });

Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: No.. That is not working. I'm using some other sln for it .. Please find my answer